# How to get len of join word?

Tags: python

```
join_word = ' '.join(word)
len_join_word = len(join_word)
```

I tried to get len of join_word but it print out nothing.

Any possible way for getting len of join_word?

Comment: That code doesn't print anything. Try adding `print len_join_word` at the end.

Comment: Did you try to `print` the output? Just assigning the value to `len_join_word` will not display any output. Also, please post the contents of `word`.

Comment: yes I print out the wrong one..Stupid me. >_<

Comment: If the `OP` has figured out why this has happened we should close this as it is too *localized* and the title does not match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly:

```
In [1]: word=['a', 'sdfs', 'sdfsdfsfs']

In [2]: join_word = ' '.join(word)

In [3]: len_join_word = len(join_word)

In [4]: print(len_join_word)
16
```

> I tried to get len of join_word but it print out nothing.

You probably don't see anything because you're not printing out the result. Try adding `print(len_join_word)` at the end.

Comment: Oh yes! it my fault. Stupid me >_<